# Talend BigQuery - SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, talend

The below query is working fine in BigQuery UI console, but throwing error in Talend.

SQL -> 
   `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM`xxx`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Talend Open Studio for Big Data

Talend Version - 7.2.1

Component Used - tBigQueryInput

Error Output

````
Running Query : SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `xxx`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
Exception in component tBigQueryInput_1 (bg)
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
"code" : 400,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Illegal operation on INFORMATION_SCHEMA view: Project_ID:xxx.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES",
"reason" : "invalid"
} ],
"message" : "Illegal operation on INFORMATION_SCHEMA view: Project_ID:xxx.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES",
"status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at gab.bg_0_1.bg$1BigQueryUtil_tBigQueryInput_1.getLocation(bg.java:459)
at gab.bg_0_1.bg$1BigQueryUtil_tBigQueryInput_1.executeQuery(bg.java:487)
at gab.bg_0_1.bg.tBigQueryInput_1Process(bg.java:571)
at gab.bg_0_1.bg.runJobInTOS(bg.java:884)
at gab.bg_0_1.bg.main(bg.java:734)```
````

Comment: Since selecting from information schema has a slightly different syntax and the projectId is not part of the select statement I suggest 1. Wrap your entire table object with backtick like this \`xxx.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES\` (instead of only around the DATASET xxx) 2. Check with Talend how the projectId is being passed alongside your query and see how you can control this value

Comment: (1) Checked. Still the same error. (2) will check with Talend and post the comments.